# How can I save the formatting of my MemoEdit correctly

Tags: vb.net, winforms, devexpress

I have a MemoEdit-field and there is a problem with the components behavoir when the user inserts a text that has more chars per line than my MemoEdit-Field.
As soon as the maximal length of a line is reached, the component breaks the line and goes on in the next line.

However these linebreaks are only "visual" which means there is no kind of linefeed added to each break.
Due to these missing linebreaks even correctly formatted texts are dissorted after saving because the user which is formatting them is unable to see if there is a carriage return linefeed or just a "visual" linebreak.
Is there a way to determine the exact index where a linebreak in a string is about to occur based on the size of the Memo-edit field?
Especially when I try to consider the individual character spacing it seems pretty hard to find an universal approach.

Answer (score 0):

The by far easiest solution is to disable the word wrap. You can achieve this by setting `memoEdit.Properties.WordWrap = false`. This will cause your editor to flow to the right instead of makeing a visual linebreak. So your User can add a linebreak manual when needed.

Getting the index where the text should be broken seems to be difficult. I came up with something like this:

```
private void memoEdit1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero))
   {
      //Get the actual line
      string text = memoEdit1.Lines[memoEdit1.Lines.Length - 1];

      //Calculate the size of the string
      SizeF size = gr.MeasureString(text, memoEdit1.Font);

      //Check if the string is as big as the memoedit
      //Notice the 50 which is constant for the width of the vertical scrollbar
      //so far you use one. You may need to fit this to your needs.
      if (size.Width >= memoEdit1.Size.Width - 50)
      {
         int index = memoEdit1.Text.Length - 1;
      }
    }
}
```

This is just an idea and you maybe need to modify this to run correct in your project. I'm not familiar with vb.net so this is C#, but should be adoptable.

Hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

There is [`EM_FMTLINES`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761570(v=vs.85).aspx) message in Win32 API. If you send this message to `TextBox` control then its `Text` property will contain soft line-break characters. Soft line-break characters is combination of `CrCrLf` characters and is used for mark the place where the line is broken because of wordwrapping.
Here is example of simple extension module:

```
Module TextBoxExtension

    Private Const EM_FMTLINES As UInteger = &HC8

    <DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
    Private Function SendMessage(hWnd As IntPtr, Msg As UInteger, wParam As Integer, lParam As IntPtr) As IntPtr
    End Function

    <Extension()>
    Public Function GetWrappedText(ByVal textBox As TextBox) As String

        Dim handle = textBox.Handle

        SendMessage(handle, EM_FMTLINES, 1, IntPtr.Zero)

        GetWrappedText = textBox.Text

        SendMessage(handle, EM_FMTLINES, 0, IntPtr.Zero)

    End Function

End Module
```

`MemoEdit` class is box which holds the instance of `TextBoxMaskBox` class. `TextBoxMaskBox` class is inherited from `System.Windows.Forms.TextBox` class. You can get it from `MemoEdit.MaskBox` property.

```
Dim text = MemoEdit1.MaskBox.GetWrappedText
```

And now you can get the lines by using `String.Split` method:

```
Dim lines = text.Split({vbCr & vbCrLf, vbCrLf, vbLf}, StringSplitOptions.None)
```